# Receiving ClassCastException when calling available() on server socket InputStream

Tags: codenameone

I am creating a server socket as per [this blog post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/sockets-multiline-trees.html) however as soon as it hits `int pending = is.available();` (line 88 of the previous link) I receive the following exception

```
[Connection 5432] 0:0:8,306 - Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException - java.net.Socket cannot be cast to com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation$SocketImpl
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.net.Socket cannot be cast to com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation$SocketImpl
    at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation.getSocketAvailableInput(AndroidImplementation.java:7420)
    at com.codename1.io.Socket$SocketInputStream.available(Socket.java:168)
    at com.adilam.aw2mob.SocketListener$SocketDataWorker.connectionEstablished(Unknown Source)
    at com.codename1.io.Socket$1Listener$1.run(Socket.java:105)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
[Listening on 5432] 0:0:8,323 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidImplementation.getSocketErrorCode(AndroidImplementation.java:7415)
    at com.codename1.io.Socket$1Listener.run(Socket.java:110)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

CN1 version is 3.7
The android version being used is 4.0

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work around the issue using a Native Interface implementation.

[This youtube vid](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html) provides a great succinct overview of invoking a native interface in CN1. I created a NativeSocketListener interface

```
public interface NativeSocketListener extends NativeInterface {
    public void SocketListener(int port);
}
```

and NativeSocketListenerImpl for android

```
public class NativeSocketListenerImpl {
    public void SocketListener(int port) {
        new Thread(new SocketListener2(port)).start();
    }

    public boolean isSupported() {
        return true;
    }

    class SocketListener2 implements Runnable {
        private ServerSocket serverSocket;

        public SocketListener2(int port) {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(e);
            }
        }

        public void run() {

            while (true) {
                try {
                    java.net.Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    while (true) {
                        int pending = is.available();
                        if (pending > 0) {
                            int size = is.read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                            if (size == -1) {
                                return;
                            }
                            if (size > 0) {
                                String data = new String(buffer, 0, size).trim();
                                // do something with the data
                            }
                        } else {
                            Thread.sleep(50);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously this implementation doesn't handle multiple connections but there are plenty of online tutorials for implementing that.

As mentioned above this is Android specific so I can't vouch for how well it works for other devices. Hopefully the upcoming release makes using a native interface unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in the server socket code we'll fix that in the next update.

Notice that what you are doing is using a listening socket which is inherently less portable and will only work on JavaSE and Android. If you use sockets we recommend client side sockets for portability using `connect` instead of `listen`.

Comment: Thanks Shai. This is an android only specialised app; not one designed for the masses so we really need to listen. Looking forward to a bug fix in the next release. (Tried adding +1 but can't be done with less than 15 rep.)

Comment: No problem, you can accept the answer with the checkbox next to it since you submitted the question and that will give you some points. The new update will be out this Friday